# I was just introduced to Hilbert Spaces, and am wondering what one of the formulas I'm using is called.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

This is the formula/normalization? Is there any specific name for this? I'm not sure what to search up to find information about it.

$\langle f | f\rangle = \int_a^b|f(x)|^2 d x$

Comment: I found it in Introduction to Formalism in Intro to Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: It's just the definition of the $L^2$ inner product specialized to the inner product of $f$ with itself.

Comment: Do you know what I would call it if I was just saying "I'm using [this definition]? Can I refer to it as anything that's not as long?

Comment: You're not using anything, this is the *definition* of the $L^2$ inner product. It's not a theorem or anything.

Comment: Ohhh, sorry. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

If $\langle \cdot | \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product of a Hilbert space, then $f \mapsto \| f \| := \sqrt{\langle f | f \rangle}$ induces a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space). In your case, it is the norm on $L^2(a,b)$.